# The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)? after dart2

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-2

I am getting error

> The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)?

after dart 2 for a form field widget.

full code:

```
class MyFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  Function onTextChanged;
  Function formValidator;
  MyFormField(
      {
      required this.onTextChanged,
      required this.formValidator,
    });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        validator: formValidator, //***** Error Here
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        onChanged: onTextChanged, //***** Error Here
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to this

```
class MyFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  Function(String?) onTextChanged; //<=note
  Function(String?) formValidator; //<=note
  MyFormField(
      {
      required this.onTextChanged,
      required this.formValidator,
    });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        validator: (String? value) => formValidator(value), //***** Error Here
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        onChanged: (String? value) => onTextChanged(value), //***** Error Here
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Because the `onChanged` function, is called when a value is entered into the form, and this value is a `string?`, because sometimes no value is entered, and you are not sure, which could be null if left empty. And your validation function and onchanged functions, need a string to compute and do logic. They get these strings from the `(String? value)` in your form fields.

Comment: now error only shows for form validator, dynamic Function(String?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)?

Comment: In the validator, remove (String? Value) and keep it `() => ...etc`

Comment: no luck, same error >The argument type 'String? Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)?'.

Comment: changing Function(String?) formValidator; to String Function(String?)? formValidator; solved the error

Comment: Awesome, good to know!